# Azure Verizon CDN profiles cannot be created with a PayAsYouGo account

Tags: azure

I am trying to create
Azure Verizon Premium CDN profiles cannot be created with a PayAsYouGo account.
I was able to create it last time on 17-Oct-2022. My account is in excellent standing with 27 subscriptions PayAsYouGo working all good in the previous 12 years

1. I can not create a new Subscription - Do you have any thoughts?
2. Azure Verizon CDN profiles cannot be created with a PayAsYouGo account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure support replied to me and that was the solution

After further research the engineering team has determined that the best path to follow to try to solve the situation is you to complete an internal takeover of the unmanaged directory which seems to be the reason why the system is preventing the subscription to be created.

Basically the next steps are:

Create a new user account
Give it Global Admin role
Use new Global Admin to perform internal takeover as per documentation :

Admin takeover of an unmanaged directory - Azure AD - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/domains-admin-takeover

Please follow the steps above and let me know if further assistance is needed